# Aggregate Query limit exceeded?

Tags: vb.net, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, fetchxml

I've got a 2 part question:

**First question**: I know that there is a query limit of 5,000 records when querying records, for performance reasons, but is there a limit when doing an aggregate query? If so, what is it? I need only to query the number of records and for one entity I can get a result of 39,000+ records, but for another entity I see an error message like:

`System.ServiceModel.FaultException 1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: AggregateQueryRecordLimit exceeded. Cannot perform this operation. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).`

I've been looking all over online but can't find anything on a query limit for aggregate/count queries.

**Second question**: Is there a simple way to query the COUNT of a large amount of records without a performance hit? I wouldn't think doing a count should require too much overhead. If there IS a limit, my idea was to implement paging in a loop and just retrieve the count for a given page while incrementing the page number each time until 0 records was returned. However, when I tried this, it seems to ignore the `page` and `count` attributes of the initial `<Fetch>` tag.

I'm wondering if there is a better/easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak much to your first issue, but it looks like [someone on MSDN may have found a workaround](http://int.social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdeployment/thread/bcd50ac2-738b-4ce6-b4fc-a43ef34fe7af). See especially the linked forum post for the practical solution.

For the second question, `COUNT` is relatively easy to handle. See the [MSDN article on FetchXML aggregates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx#count) for lots of examples.

```
<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
    <entity name='opportunity'> 
       <attribute name='name' alias='opportunity_count' aggregate='count'/> 
    </entity> 
</fetch>
```

The generated SQL for that query will be as follows:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS opportunity_count
FROM
    Opportunity
```

Comment: Thank you. Like I said, I've got a pretty simple FetchXML query that is already returning the counts, I think it's just when the total count is over 50,000. I was hoping to not have to make any DB changes but it looks like that may be the only option. That, or a registry change.

Comment: @lhan16: OK, I see what you were saying now. Outside of this and direct database queries, all I can say is "Good luck!"

Comment: I think what I am going to do (as I've been told a DB change or Registry change is not an option at this point) is just catch the "query limit exceeded" error and display the total count as "50,000+". Thanks for the input and links!!

Comment: updated link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcd50ac2-738b-4ce6-b4fc-a43ef34fe7af/dynamics-crm-2011-performance-impact-of-aggregatequeryrecordlimit-change